# How to find length of a rectangular tile when viewing at some angle

Tags: geometry

I have a question on angles.

I have a rectangular tile. when looking straight I can find the width of the tile, but how do I find the apparent width when I see the same rectangular tile at some angle. Below I have attached an image for more clarity. So how do I find y in the image below?
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that you have fully specified the problem. May be you have, but in a sense the answer depends also on the distance! If you think about this in the "real world" you would observe that the vertical line that is further away from you will no longer have length $t$. This will also have (in all but relatively extreme cases) a minute effect on $y$. Mathematica largely hides this from the user by rescaling the displayed image, but you do see a perspective change just like this in its 3D-graphics. I don't know the details, but IIRC scaling the Viewpoint variable changes this a bit.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Well got my point. Actually the side that I have shown in the image is a side of a cube. I am drawing a 3D cube object.So when viewing the cube from little up and little right then the two sides of the cube are visible in this shape. So I want to calculate that width. Also, in this particular question I didn't care about the value of `t` so I just put it that way.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your projection. If you assume orthogonal projection, so that the apparent length of line segments is independent of their distance the way your images suggest, then you cannot solve this, since a rectangle of any aspect ratio might appear as a rectangle of any other aspect ratio by simply aligning it with the image plane and then rotating it around one of its axes of symmetry. So you can't deduce the original aspect ratio from the apparent one, much less the original lengths.